# Scope of the variables when processed in a function

Tags: jquery, function, scope

I've got this function to rebuild some input into the links (I need to get rid of spaces, commas, special characters - that kind of stuff):

```
function linkbuilding(a) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(' ',a)){
        a = a.replace(/ /g, "-");
    }

    if (jQuery.inArray(',',a)){
        a = a.replace(/,/g, "");
    }

    if (jQuery.inArray('ë',a)){
        a = a.replace(/ë/g, "e");
    }

    console.log(a + " value");
}

var plantNameLinkBuild = jQuery("span.plant-name");
plantNameLinkBuild.each(function(){
    var lnkName = jQuery(this).text().trim();
    linkbuilding( lnkName );
    jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="../kruiden-a-z/'+lnkName+'"></a>');
});
```

So the function linkbuilding rans on lnkName (linkbuilding( lnkName )), from console.log I see that the values change.

But it doesn't update `lnkName` variable original input - I don't get the corrected values. So I get in the end still the link with spaces etc.

Where am I wrong? How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You're only changing a local copy of `lnkName`. You have to return the changed value from `linkbuilding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lnkName` variable is passed by value, not by reference, hence you need to make the function return the new value, then update the original variable with the result of the function:

```
function linkbuilding(a) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(' ',a)) {
        a = a.replace(/ /g, "-");
    }

    if (jQuery.inArray(',',a)){
        a = a.replace(/,/g, "");
    }

    if (jQuery.inArray('ë',a)){
        a = a.replace(/ë/g, "e");
    }

    console.log(a + " value");
    return a;
}

var plantNameLinkBuild = jQuery("span.plant-name");

plantNameLinkBuild.each(function(){
    var lnkName = jQuery(this).text().trim();
    lnkName = linkbuilding( lnkName );
    jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="../kruiden-a-z/'+lnkName+'"></a>');
});
```

Or just:

```
var lnkName = linkbuilding(jQuery(this).text().trim());
```

Also note that you can simplify the `linkbuilding()` function by using regular expressions:

```
function linkbuilding(text) {
    return text.replace(/,/g, '').replace(/ë/g, 'e').replace(/\s+/g, '-');
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Ledebv3d/1)

Comment: `a` is not an array ?

Comment: It's a string, which can be traversed by index to check each individual character

Comment: Was not aware that a string could be passed to `$.inArray`

Comment: Thank you every much @Rory McCrossan! it's working. I see now what I was missing.  Also for advise to simplify the linkbuilding() :-) awesome!